# Type check error in Haskell monad chaining

Tags: haskell, dictionary, monads

I'm new to Haskell and I'm just following the example on RWH. I'm having problems with the following programs on Chapter 14:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

type PersonName = String
type PhoneNumber = String
type BillingAddress = String
data MobileCarrier = Honest_Bobs_Phone_Network
                   | Morrisas_Marvelous_Mobiles
                   | Petes_Plutocratic_Phones
                     deriving (Eq, Ord)

findCarrierBillingAddress :: PersonName
                          -> M.Map PersonName PhoneNumber
                          -> M.Map PhoneNumber MobileCarrier
                          -> M.Map MobileCarrier BillingAddress
                          -> Maybe BillingAddress
-- This will work
findCarrierBillingAddress person phoneMap carrierMap addressMap = do
  phone <- M.lookup person phoneMap
  carrier <- M.lookup phone carrierMap
  address <- M.lookup carrier addressMap
  return address

-- This will NOT work:
findCarrierBillingAddress person phoneMap carrierMap addressMap =
    return person >>=
    lookup phoneMap >>=
    lookup carrierMap >>=
    lookup addressMap
  where lookup = flip M.lookup
```

It seems that when writing findCarrierBillingAddres in the monad chaining format using >>=, it just does not type check:

```
/home/bruce/Programming/haskell/real/ch14/hello.hs:21:9:
    Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `MobileCarrier'
    Expected type: MobileCarrier -> Maybe BillingAddress
      Actual type: PersonName -> Maybe BillingAddress
    In the return type of a call of `lookup'
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `lookup addressMap'
    In the expression:
      return person >>= lookup phoneMap >>= lookup carrierMap
      >>= lookup addressMap

/home/bruce/Programming/haskell/real/ch14/hello.hs:21:16:
    Couldn't match type `MobileCarrier' with `[Char]'
    Expected type: M.Map PersonName BillingAddress
      Actual type: M.Map MobileCarrier BillingAddress
    In the first argument of `lookup', namely `addressMap'
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `lookup addressMap'
    In the expression:
      return person >>= lookup phoneMap >>= lookup carrierMap
      >>= lookup addressMap
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

The question is.. why the second format using >>= would not type check?

Comment: You should make person the last argument.  It seems better for partial application.  And you can rewrite using Kleisli composition, <=<.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just the monomorphism restriction acting up again. Since you have a pattern binding with no type signature the inferred type is monomorphic and therefore determined by the first usage.

Just change it to

```
lookup m k = flip M.lookup m k
```

or even

```
lookup m = flip M.lookup m
```

You just have to convince GHC to generalize the function which it won't do when it's just a simple pattern binding. Adding a parameter turns it into a function binding which means that it will be fully generalized.

If I lost you a bit up there, I've [blogged about this](http://www.dannygratzer.com/2013/07/the-monomorphism-restriction.html)

Comment: @jk. I'm glad you enjoyed it :)

Answer (score 7):

You are being hit with the [Monomorphism Restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction)
when the type inferencer is trying to deduce the type for your local
`lookup` function.

Rather than deducing the most general type, it determines from the first use
of `lookup` that it should have the type `lookup :: Map [Char] [Char] ->
[Char] -> Maybe [Char]`, which cannot be unified when you then try to use it
on values of `Map [Char] MobileCarrier`.

Your first option is to disable the Monomorphism Restriction with the pragma
`{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}`. The second option is to add
a type signature to `lookup` as so

```
findCarrierBillingAddress person phoneMap carrierMap addressMap =
    return person >>=
    lookup phoneMap >>=
    lookup carrierMap >>=
    lookup addressMap
  where lookup :: Ord k => M.Map k a -> k -> Maybe a
        lookup = flip M.lookup
```